# Keras - How to fit an object in model

Tags: python, keras

i'm trying to fit an object into the keras model,

i have a structure similar to this (as input) with variable length:

```
[
 { "Item_73851": [[5, 0.64], [2, 0.01], [12, 0.20]],
   "Item_928": [[8, 0.52]],
   "Item_78": [],
   "Item_464": [[43, 0.02], [1, 0.03], [6, 0.07]],
   "category": "B1" },
 { "Item_73851": [[3, 0.03], [17, 0.42]],
   "Item_928": [],
   "Item_78": [],
   "Item_464": [[27, 0.07]],
   "category": "B1" }
]
```

as you can see Item_(N) can be empty or contain another object with a variable length, the content of category can also vary

is it possible somehow to fit this object into keras to correctly train it?

if a reshape is needed how i can not loose the "Item_(N)" key -> array since the (N) is not an index (it can be "Alpha", "Bravo" etc..) ?

Comment: it's not about programming with keras exactly, it's' about missing values in classification.

Comment: right but some values are missing, what if i populate the arrays with 0.00 based on the maximum value found? p.s. i have updated the object example